# CentOS 7 has no login UI

Tags: centos

I have a system that running the CentOS 7. When I sit in front of the computer physically, it shows the background and taskbar but the background is blank. It does not show profile pic, username and password input. However, it works fine using SSH or VNC. VNC can see the login UI like below. Any idea what is going on?

[image]

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

Comment: What is it that it does show?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Basically it shows background and taskbar but the background is blank. There is no profile pic, username and password input. I have edited the description

Comment: I think I found the reason after Ctrl+Alt+F2. I saw "A start job is running for Wait for Plymouth Boot screen to quit".

Comment: eventually, I use `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target` to boot to command line. Login in command line and startx to go into Desktop UI.